# Magento sales_order_create grid - possible to add an if statement?

Tags: php, sql, magento

I need the sales_order_create grid to show the special price, and I've done so by adding:

```
->addAttributeToSelect('special_price')
```

To the _prepareCollection() function, and then adding:

```
$this->addColumn('special_price', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Special Price'),
    'column_css_class' => 'price',
    'align'     => 'center',
    'type'      => 'currency',
    'currency_code' => $this->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(),
    'rate'      => $this->getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getRate($this->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode()),
    'index'     => 'special_price',
    'renderer'  => 'adminhtml/sales_order_create_search_grid_renderer_price',
));
```

To the _prepareColumns() function.

This works, there is now a price column and a special_price column.

My question is, is it possible to combine the 2 columns with an if statement or something similar?

Ideally I'd like one price column that displays the special_price in bold if there is one, and if not shows the normal price.

IF special_price IS NOT NULL then special_price ELSE price  << that kind of thing

Hopefully I've made myself clear!

Edit: as requested, here is the full _prepareCollection() function:

(the only line I added was  ->addAttributeToSelect('special_price'))

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $attributes = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes();
    /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $collection
        ->setStore($this->getStore())
        ->addAttributeToSelect($attributes)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('product_size')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('special_price')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array_keys(
            Mage::getConfig()->getNode('adminhtml/sales/order/create/available_product_types')->asArray()
        ))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('gift_message_available');

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addSaleableFilterToCollection($collection);

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Comment: good question. How did you add your special price field in collection. Show that code

Comment: Hi, i've added the entire _prepareCollection() function to my original question, I hope this is what you meant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea  is good. But I think this is not possible at all as per my understanding. This is because `special_price` and normal price are two different attributes. What `_prepareColumn()` does is, it simply create a column for each attribute those are specified inside that method using `addColumn`.

Now suppose you have two orders. Let it be `Order A` and `Order B`. For order A, we have special price and for order B we dont have a special product. Now if we tried to show those columns seperately, it will distruct grid list. ie

```
    NAME       SPECIAL PRICE    NORMAL PRICE
    .........................................
     Order A       $10              nope

     Order B       nope              $5
   ..........................................
```

First row try to hide normal price column while second row try to hide special price column. This is definitely an **ambiguous situation**.  So you cannot simply show only one attribute out of from multiple attributes, since you are dealing with a collection.

Hope you get me !

Comment: That makes sense! I thought it would be tricky.  Is there no way to add a single column, and within that column put an IF statement?

Comment: nope.. there is not in my knowledge. What you are trying to achieve is not possible